# Consuming WSDL with multidimentional array with WSDL.exe fails

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl.exe

I have the following in a WSDL I am consuming;

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeClassType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="errorMessage" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1">     </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element type="tp:ArrayOfArrayOfString" name="values" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1">     </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element type="xsd:boolean" name="isEmpty" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">      </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

where

```
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfArrayOfString">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
      <xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[,]"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However using **wsdl.exe** from MS (Runtime Version: 1.1.4322.573) generates

```
    public class SomeClassType {

        /// 
        public string errorMessage;

        /// 
        public string[] values;

        /// 
        public bool isEmpty;

    }
```

I expected `string[,] values` not `string[] values`

Is there a fix or a work around to this problem? (other than manually changing the generated code)

Comment: Step one: maybe you shouldn't be using obsolete versions of .NET? Step two: maybe you should be using WCF instead? Try it at least, to see if svcutil.exe can handle the WSDL and produce reasonable code. Step three: are you at least running the latest service pack of .NET 1.1? Step four: try .NET 2.0, which is largely the fix to .NET 1.1.

Comment: @John: not my call to make. stuck in the past. .NET1.1 or bust.

Comment: @John: I have tried this with Visual Studio Express 2010 (which is framework 4 right?) and it fails there too. So it looks like it is not a framework issue...

Comment: @Asher: sorry to hear that. RPC/Encoded services are difficult, if not impossible, to use. They're not WS-I BP 1.1 compliant.

Comment: @John: Do you know how to specify a multidimensional array type in the WSDL so that .NET tools will consume it properly?

Comment: It's not a question of the array - it's a question of how the service is implemented. If you want, try creating a service yourself that returns a similar multi-dimensional array, and look to see what kind of WSDL .NET produces.

Comment: @John: I had to set the 
type="tp:ArrayOfArrayOfString" to type="tp:ArrayOfString"
and the maxOccurs="unbounded".

Comment: @Asher: post that as an answer, and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the `type="tp:ArrayOfArrayOfString"` to `type="tp:ArrayOfString"` and the `maxOccurs="unbounded"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try the WCF proxy generator (I believe WCF uses some other util, not wsdl.exe) - maybe that would be useful, but if that fails - I think that manually editing the generated code is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Try svcutil.exe.  it is advisable to try a newer version of .net.